# Index and count must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: count

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, count

i'm getting mad with this error! The complete error is:

```
[ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and count must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: count]
System.String.RemoveInternal(Int32 startIndex, Int32 count) +0
System.String.Remove(Int32 startIndex, Int32 count) +22
Digi_Proveedores.SiteMaster.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\INV\Digi_Proveedores\Digi_Proveedores\Site.Master.cs:16
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +146
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

The code of the Digi_Proveedores.SiteMaster.Page_Load is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Usuario;
        Usuario = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
        Usuario = Usuario.Remove(0, 13);
        DBConnection Mov = new DBConnection();
        lbl_User.Text = Mov.ConsultaUsuario(Usuario);
    }
```

When i excecute the code in my local pc it's works fine, the problem is at the ISS7.

I can't understand how can i solve the error. If anyone can help i'd be really grateful.

Thanks!.

Comment: Could you please share the code at `Digi_Proveedores.SiteMaster.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\User\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\INV\Digi_Proveedores\Digi_Proveedores\Site.Master.cs:16`? This looks like C#; if it is - could you please also tag your question?

Comment: I've already updated the post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove 13 characters from the string, containing less that 13; that is what error stated. What is the content of Usuario after the first assignemt?

```
    Usuario = Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"];
    Usuario = Usuario.Remove(0, 13);
```

Comment: Thanks to you, i could find the error. Was a problem whit the windows authentication. thank you very much!